# How to specify the order of Java Object initialization

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, reflection

I have the following class:

```
public class Action implements Serializable {
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Action.class);
    private Integer actionID;
    private Integer actionStatus;
    private User    user;
    private Date    actionDueDate;

    public Action(User user) {
    this.setUser(user);
}

public Action() {
}

     getters...
     setters...
}
```

I need to initialize `user` property before the `actionDueDate` can be initialized, because `actionDueDate` is dependent of user's timezone.
I can use the constructor that calls the right away to initialize user, but I am using Hibernate and it uses default constructor to populate the object.
How can I make sure that `user` property is always initialized before `actionDueDate` property. What approach shall I follow.
Is there any way to ensure that initialization order can be specified in Java?
Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to specify that initialization order in Java (maybe in Hibernate).

Try this:

- In setActionDueDate verify if the user "is already there" ( user != null ) if so then initialize actionDueDate otherwise store its "uninitialized value" somethere else.
- In setUser verify if actionDueDate has already been "stored". If so, then finish the initialization, else leave it as is.

this would cover the two possible cases.